# Removing page number from title frame without changing the Warsaw theme

Tags: beamer

I applied the idea of [Removing page number from title frame without changing the theme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82794/removing-page-number-from-title-frame-without-changing-the-theme) in my beamer presentation slides. I am using Warsaw theme. However, modifications made by me in the latex code for beamer presentation slides using Warsaw theme is not correct. My code is:

```
\documentclass {beamer}

\mode<beamer>{\usetheme{Warsaw}}
\title[Test Short Title]{Test Long Title}

\begin{document}
\bgroup
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1ex,rightskip=1.5em]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%

   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1ex,leftskip=1.5em]{title in head/foot}%
   \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle{}\hspace*{2em}
%    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
    \hspace*{6ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\egroup

\setcounter{framenumber}{0}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First test frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Second test frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\item Item 4
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Third test frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame} More \end{frame}

\end{document}

Kindly guide me what to do.

Eagerly waiting for your valuable response.

With regards,

Abhaya Kumar
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I removed your mail address -- posting the mail is not recommend and not necessary at all.

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure what your problem is. I'd hazard a guess that you want the framecount on all slides but the titlepage. Am I correct?

Comment: How about simply using `\begin{frame}[plain] \titlepage \end{frame}` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the frame option `noframenumbering`:

```
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
 \titlepage
\end{frame}

% OR

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering] 
    \maketitle  %\def\maketitle{\ifbeamer@inframe\titlepage\else\frame{\titlepage}\fi}
\end{frame}
```